# Is there a Perl shortcut to count the number of matches in a string?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, perl4

Suppose I have:

```
my $string = "one.two.three.four";
```

How should I play with context to get the number of times the pattern found a match (3)?  Can this be done using a one-liner?

I tried this:

```
my ($number) = scalar($string=~/\./gi);
```

I thought that by putting parentheses around `$number`, I'd force array context, and by the use of `scalar`, I'd get the count. However, all I get is `1`.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

That puts the regex itself in scalar context, which isn't what you want. Instead, put the regex in list context (to get the number of matches) and put *that* into scalar context.

```
 my $number = () = $string =~ /\./gi;
```

Comment: Well, perlsecret does propose "Saturn" as an alternate name. :)

Comment: Can someone explain this bit of code to me? I'm new to perl and I'm still not really comfortable with contexts.

Comment: The first part, `() = $string =~ /\./gi`, make the match operator return the results of the match in a list context. This is similar to `my @results = $string =~ /\./gi;`. Next, the `my $number` part is a scalar value. Assigning the results of the list context to a scalar returns its length. This is the same as `my $count = @some_list`, which returns the length of the array. My answer below is another way of visualizing the behavior here.

Answer (score 41):

I think the clearest way to describe this would be to avoid the instant-cast to scalar.  First assign to an array, and then use that array in scalar context.  That's basically what the `= () =` idiom will do, but without the (rarely used) idiom:

```
my $string = "one.two.three.four";
my @count = $string =~ /\./g;
print scalar @count;
```

Comment: +1 for the most straightforward way, goatse operator is scary.

Comment: Parentheses around `@count` are unnecessary though.

Answer (score 25):

Also, see [Perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string%3F) :

> There are a number of ways, with varying efficiency. If you want a count of a certain single character (X) within a string, you can use the tr/// function like so:
>
> ```
> $string = "ThisXlineXhasXsomeXx'sXinXit";
> $count = ($string =~ tr/X//);
> print "There are $count X characters in the string";
> ```
>
> This is fine if you are just looking for a single character. However, if you are trying to count multiple character substrings within a larger string, tr/// won't work. What you can do is wrap a while() loop around a global pattern match. For example, let's count negative integers:
>
> ```
> $string = "-9 55 48 -2 23 -76 4 14 -44";
> while ($string =~ /-\d+/g) { $count++ }
> print "There are $count negative numbers in the string";
> ```
>
> Another version uses a global match in list context, then assigns the result to a scalar, producing a count of the number of matches.
>
> ```
> $count = () = $string =~ /-\d+/g;
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Is the following code a one-liner?

```
print $string =~ s/\./\./g;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
my $string = "one.two.three.four";
my ($number) = scalar( @{[ $string=~/\./gi ]} );
```

It returns `3` for me. By creating a reference to an array the regular expression is evaluated in list context and the `@{..}` de-references the array reference.

Comment: You don't need any of those parenthesis.

Comment: I must say I like this method better than goatse. In fact I like pretty much everything better than goatse.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that if you have an OR condition in your regular expression (eg `/(K..K)|(V.AK)/gi` ) then the array produced may have undefined elements which are included in the count at the end.

For example:

```
my $seq = "TSYCSKSNKRCRRKYGDDDDWWRSQYTTYCSCYTGKSGKTKGGDSCDAYYEAYGKSGKTKGGRNNR";
my $regex = '(K..K)|(V.AK)';
my $count = () = $seq =~ /$regex/gi;
print "$count\n";
```

Gives a value of count of 6.

I found the solution in this post
[How do I remove all undefs from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122977/how-do-i-remove-all-undefs-from-array)

```
my $seq = "TSYCSKSNKRCRRKYGDDDDWWRSQYTTYCSCYTGKSGKTKGGDSCDAYYEAYGKSGKTKGGRNNR";
my $regex = '(K..K)|(V.AK)';
my @count = $seq =~ /$regex/gi;
@count = grep defined, @count; 
my $count = scalar @count;
print "$count\n";
```

Which then gives the correct answer of three.

Answer (score -1):

another way,

```
my $string = "one.two.three.four";
@s = split /\./,$string;
print scalar @s - 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Friedo's method is: `$a = () = $b =~ $c`.

But it's possible to simplify this even further to just `($a) = $b =~ $c`, like so :

```
my ($matchcount) = $text =~ s/$findregex/ /gi;
```

You could thank just wrap this up in a function, `getMatchCount()`, and not worry about it destroying the passed string.

On the other hand, you can add in a swap, which may be a bit more computation, but does not result in altering the string.

```
my ($matchcount) = $text =~ s/($findregex)/$1/gi;
```

Comment: Except that this is a substitution, not a match: it will destroy the original string. And it is the same idea as @Mike had 6 years earlier.

Comment: @fishinear: This is very different than Mike.  He was capable of printing it, but not storing it to a variable.  The difference is significant.

Comment: If you need nondestructive, just s/(regex)/$1/g or /(=regex)//g if you like living dangerously.

Comment: @android.weasel Oh, hey, good point!  Updating with that remark.  I normally wrap stuff like this in functions, so I myself don't have to worry about the destructability of passed args (not sure which is faster, because now it's doing a swap).  But that is useful info, adding!

Answer (score -1):

```
my $count = 0;
my $pos = -1;
while (($pos = index($string, $match, $pos+1)) > -1) {
  $count++;
}
```

checked with Benchmark, it's pretty fast

Comment: That's not a pattern match.