# Count uppercase letters in string using perl

Tags: string, perl, character, uppercase

I want to count the number of upper case letters in a string using perl.

For example: I need to know how many upper case characters the word "EeAEzzKUwUHZws" contains.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Beware of Unicode, as the straight A-Z thing isn't really portable for other characters, such as accented uppercase letters. if you need to handle these too, try:

```
my $result = 0;
$result++ while($string =~ m/\p{Uppercase}/g);
```

Comment: or just `$result = () = $string =~ m/\p{Uppercase}/g`

Comment: Do remember that `Uppercase` (alias `upper`) comprises more than merely `Uppercase_Letter` (alias `Lu`), although the former is more often appropirate than the latter is.  Both, of course, ignore titlecase when those are distinct from uppercase.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `tr` operator:

```
$upper_case_letters = $string =~ tr/A-Z//;
```

This is a common question and the `tr` operator [usually outperforms other techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813768/how-can-i-count-characters-in-perl/3813819#3813819).

Comment: Well sure, but if you don’t care whether it gets the right answer or not, I can make any bit of code infinitely fast. ;(

Answer (score 2):

```
sub count {
  $t = shift;
  $x = 0;   
  for( split//,$t ) {
    $x++ if m/[A-Z]/;
  }
  return $x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one-liner method is:

```
$count = () = $string =~ m/\p{Uppercase}/g
```

This is based off [Stuart Watt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6652900/480943) but modified according to the [tip that ysth posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652757/count-uppercase-letters-in-string-using-perl#comment7865186_6652900) in the comments to make it a one-liner.