# What is the equivalent of “grep -n” in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to grep a word with line number. It's easily possible in the shell with the command `grep -n` or with `sed`. Is there any equivalent available in Perl? I have checked the [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) function, however I am unable to find anything like I need.

Comment: I guess here is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849329/is-there-a-perl-shortcut-to-count-the-number-of-matches-in-a-string

Comment: No, the number of matches is different to the line number of the match.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a file called mygrep:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $match = shift;

while (<>) {
  if (/\Q$match/) {
    print "$. : $_";
  }
}
```

Then from the command line:

```
$ ./mygrep if mygrep 
6 : my $match = shift;
9 :   if (/\Q$match/) {
```

Should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Hey It's good ! But what about multiple matches within multiple files...like `grep -n "word" *` or with `xargs` etc. Do i need to write a loop for each file after `ls`?

Comment: Like I said, it's enough to get you started :-) I think your other questions will be answered if you read the documentation for $. (in perldoc perlvar).

Comment: Seems a bit excessive to write this as a script.  You can do it easily as a one-liner: perl -wne 'print "$.: $_" if m/\Qmatch/'

Comment: @William Pursell - yes but @davorg has written something that someone just learning Perl will benefit from.

Comment: @William Pursell: Sure, but the program version is far easier to change to add the other bells and whistles that mandy asked for.

Comment: @Nic Gibson Someone just learning perl will benefit greatly from learning -p/-n early on.

Comment: @mandy no, it already does that thanks to the magic of `while (<>)`. Although it doesn't tell you *which* file the match was in — to get that, you want to add `$ARGV` to the print line :)

Comment: Working well for a single file for me. But doesn't glob. Is it supposed to work on ActiveState Perl on Windows?