# search motif print header

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with multiple strings; say data.fa.

```
sp|P08246|ELNE_HUMAN Neutrophil elastase OS=Homo sapiens GN=ELANE PE=1 SV=1
MTLGRRLACLFLACVLPALLLGGTALASEIVGGRRARPHAWPFMVSLQLRGGHFCGATLI
APNFVMSAAHCVANVNVRAVRVVLGAHNLSRREPTRQVFAVQRIFENGYDPVNLLNDIVI
LQLNGSATINANVQVAQLPAQGRRLGNGVQCLAMGWGLLGRNRGIASVLQELNVTVVTSL
CRRSNVCTLVRGRQAGVCFGDSGSPLVCNGLIHGIASFVRGGCASGLYPDAFAPVAQFVN
WIDSIIQRSEDNPCPHPRDPDPASRTHGGGGNGVQCLAMGWG
sp|P31689|DNJA1_HUMAN DnaJ homolog subfamily A member 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=DNAJA1 PE=1 SV=2
MVKETTYYDVLGVKPNATQEELKKAYRKLALKYHPDKNPNEGEKFKQISQAYEVLSDAKK
RELYDKGGEQAIKEGGAGGGFGSPMDIFDMFFGGGGRMQRERRGKNVVHQLSVTLEDLYN
GATRKLALQKNVICDKCEGRGGKKGAVECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMEC
QGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDII
sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
MQPILLLLAFLLLPRADAGEIIGGHEAKPHSRPYMAYLMIWDQKSLKRCGGFLIRDDFVL
TAAHCWGSSINVTLGAHNIKEQEPTQQFIPVKRPIPHPAYNPKNFSNDIMLLQLERKAKR
TRAVQPLRLPSNKAQVKPGQTCSVAGWGQTAPLGKHSHTLQEVKMTVQEDRKCESDLRHY
YDSTIELCVGDPEIKKTSFKGDSGGPLVCNKVAQGIVSYGRNNGMPPRACTKVSSFVHWI
KKTMKRYGNGVQCLAMGWG
```

I am trying to print the header and the no of motifs (GNGVQCLAMGWG) if any on an output file.
Yeah ! it's a newbie here. I have the following code

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print STDOUT "Enter the motif: ";
my $motif = <STDIN>;
chomp $motif;

my %seqs = %{ read_fasta_as_hash( 'data.fa' ) };
foreach my $id ( keys %seqs ) {
    if ( $seqs{$id} =~ /$motif/ ) {
        print $id, "\n";
        print $seqs{$id}, "\n";
    }
}

sub read_fasta_as_hash {
    my $fn = shift;

    my $current_id = '';
    my %seqs;
    open FILE, "<$fn" or die $!;
    while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
        chomp $line;
        if ( $line =~ /^(>.*)$/ ) {
            $current_id  = $1;
        } elsif ( $line !~ /^\s*$/ ) { # skip blank lines
            $seqs{$current_id} .= $line
        }
    }
    close FILE or die $!;

    return \%seqs;
}
```

I am expecting output like:

```
sp|P08246|ELNE_HUMAN Neutrophil elastase OS=Homo sapiens GN=ELANE PE=1 SV=1: 02
sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2: 01
```

I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here:

```
if ( $seqs{$id} =~ /$motif/ ) {
    print $id, "\n";
    print $seqs{$id}, "\n";
}
```

You're close to the mark, but doing unnecessary work. If all we need is the [number of matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849329/is-there-a-perl-shortcut-to-count-the-number-of-matches-in-a-string), we can do simply count and [format the result](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to get your leading zero:

```
my $matches = () = $seqs{$id} =~ /$motif/g;
if ($matches > 0) {
    my $matches_string = sprintf('%02d', $matches);
    print "$id: $matches_string\n";
}
```

As an aside, if there's any chance that `$motif` will ever contain regex metacharacters (and you might as well assume it could), you can [escape it](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences):

```
#not escaped
/$motif/g

#escaped
/\Q$motif\E/g
```

Finally, do you need the results in any particular order? The keys operator doesn't guarantee that you'll get keys out in the same order they're inserted.

Comment: Not really, but the most preferred part is the output order i.e,

Comment: Not really, but the most preferred part is the output order i.e, >FASTA_header1: number of motifs

Comment: Some of the functions are real hard to fit in my brain. Could you please type in the actual script for  me to run. Thanks Rutter.

Comment: As an output, in addition to the "Fasta header:count of matches"; is it possible to get the length of each string as well?

Comment: @user3489854 Perl uses [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) to get a string's length. Be careful about whether or not you want to count newlines and so forth, though.